# PHP - Create new links or redirection with slugged new strings for my web pages

Tags: php, slug

I have a football/soccer website, where the main content is a profile for each player.
The current URLs are following this format:
http://www.cadistas1910.com/ficha_jugador.php?idjugador=1356

I want to change them for something more SEO friendly, basically slug strings, to something like:
http://www.cadistas1910.com/ficha-jugador/ruben-yanez

After navigating through this forum, I was able to find fantastic PHP functions that get me to generate the second string as desired.

But as much as I try to find how to make the new created URL be able to redirect to the actual physical link that works (first one)...how the hell do I do this? There is no php file in the second URL to make a redirection...I know this must be quite simple, but I am totally lost here!

Thanks a lot in advanced for your help!

Comment: Half of the magic happens in the webserver. Are you using a PHP framework? And what webserver are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)